# CSS not loading in Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

Website: www.abbotsley.com

CSS is not loading for this particular website with Chrome.  Worked perfectly fine yesterday.  Also works completely fine on my Chromebook, but not on my desktop.  Works fine with Firefox and IE.

Trying to access the `/wp-admin/` for the page also gives me a privacy error - again, this doesn't happen with Firefox or IE.

Any idea what I can do to fix this?  It's a WordPress website.

Comment: Appears to work just fine on my system. My browser is Google Chrome as well.

Comment: Really weird how it is only affecting my desktops Chrome browser...

Comment: it's hard to say. something weird was happening to my chrome after I updated it to 44, but it only happened for a day.

Comment: There might be errors (which might be easily overlooked) in your CSS. I had a similar problem and found a minor error in my CSS (such as missing "}"...) Some browsers may ignore certain errors but some may not.

Answer (score 2):

Tmeal, this same issue has been happening on my company website. I have done a bit of digging and from what I have found, it is the Chrome update to 44 that is causing it. We have had 4 staff upgrade to 44 and they all have the same issue. I tried your website on my computer (still running 43) and it works perfectly, but then tested it on another machine with 44 and it displays incorrectly.

I tried clearing the cache and it work as it should for a while and then reverted back to having an issue.

---

I have sorted this issue on my website. I have the wooCommerce plugin installed  which needs to be updated to 2.3.13. I hope this works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

Here works fine in Google Chrome. Try to redefine your Chrome or clear cache.